# Buildozer Problem. I try to make apk file for android, but i cant

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

```
    artur@DESKTOP-SMKQONQ:~/Suka$ ls
    buildozer.spec  main.py
    artur@DESKTOP-SMKQONQ:~/Suka$ buildozer android debug
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 10, in <module>
         sys.exit(main())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
      packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
      Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
         packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 122, in __init__
      self.config.read(filename, "utf-8")
    TypeError: read() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I dont understand what wrong. I completely install all the packages for kivy and buildozer which are described there https://github.com/kivy/buildozer. Help me please!

Comment: do you have [`requirements = python2,kivy`](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer#installing-buildozer-with-target-python-2) in your `buildozer.spec` file?

Comment: Yes, it is stil the same problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.38.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.config.read(filename, "utf-8")
TypeError: read() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
New problem now

Comment: That is a [bug that was introduced a few days ago in a recent commit](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/commit/c66af5dc0bf7420df6d71c26bee55f085b80c93b), either wait until it is fixed then update again, or downgrade back to `buildozer==0.37`

Comment: an issue has been notified to the developers (https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/commit/c66af5dc0bf7420df6d71c26bee55f085b80c93b#commitcomment-31965514) as developer noted: "Until it gets fixed you can use specific commit when installing buildozer:

`pip install --upgrade https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/archive/6b004f9778a312fed6908bceef605e4ef8c1efe9.zip` "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to davedwards. I`ve solved this problem by install buildozer version 0.37:

```
pip install --upgrade 
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/archive/6b004f9778a312fed6908bceef605e4ef8c1efe9.zip
```

Actually, it is a bug with new version buildozer.