# python kivy app gives error: "cannot import name 'osc' from 'kivy.lib'"

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer, osc

After compiling and deploying my kivy app on my android phone I get this error when staring the app (it includes an osc service). What can be the cause?

```
02-03 11:10:59.839 21140 21172 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/com.keinert.stayalive/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-02-03_1.txt
02-03 11:10:59.839 21140 21172 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-Unknown, 20190203
02-03 11:10:59.840 21140 21172 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Feb  3 2019, 09:58:20) 
02-03 11:10:59.840 21140 21172 I python  : [Clang 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55
02-03 11:10:59.932 21140 21172 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
02-03 11:11:00.428 21140 21172 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
02-03 11:11:00.544 21140 21172 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
02-03 11:11:00.581 21140 21172 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
02-03 11:11:00.581 21140 21172 I python  :    File "/home/joachim/PycharmProjects/StayAlive/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
02-03 11:11:00.583 21140 21172 I python  :  ImportError: cannot import name 'osc' from 'kivy.lib' (/data/user/0/com.keinert.stayalive/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/lib/__init__.pyc)
02-03 11:11:00.583 21140 21172 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I don't know why it let me build the apk with buildozer but when running on android it failed.

the build lists the oscpy:

```
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     stayalive: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy, oscpy, cython), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
[INFO]:    stayalive has compatible recipes, using this one
```

and here is the info about the code levels:
sdk 24
ndk 17c
Android API target 26
NDK revision 17.2.4988734
Buildozer 0.38.dev0  (used because of this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54208752/buildozer-problem-i-try-to-make-apk-file-for-android-but-i-cant))

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended by the kivy team that you don't use the old `osc` library, and instead use the new [oscpy](https://github.com/kivy/oscpy).